# Using Job schedule to input current date and time into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have 2 databases, first being Oracle and the second being SQL Server. I am able to connect the 2 databases together and data sync between the 2 databases are possible. However, I would like to know if, I can automatically insert the database's system date and time upon each entry into the table?

For example, in this case, when the data gets transferred over from Oracle, I would like the `TIMEUPDATE` data to mirror the real timing in SQL Server and not the data from Oracle.

I have already scripted this to create the database. All the data in my Oracle database are successfully transferfed to my SQL Server. The `TimeUpdate` column is created.

Sample data:

```
ID  NAME    TIMEUPDATE
---------------------------------------
 1  John    2019-09-13 04:42:31.1320000
22  Mary    2019-09-09 04:42:43.6570000
 3  Tommy   2019-09-17 04:42:47.0220000
 4  Jill    2019-09-06 04:42:50.1170000
 5  Sam     2019-09-25 04:42:51.9230000
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO Customers
FROM OPENQUERY(NEWTABLE, 'SELECT ID, NAME, TIMEUPDATE FROM CUSTOMER')
```

Comment: I suggest maintaining a single logical database if you have requirements like this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hi, that has been the plan the whole time

Comment: Try to use a trigger at SQL server end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
INTO Customers
FROM OPENQUERY(NEWTABLE, 'SELECT ID, NAME, SYSDATE AS TIMEUPDATE FROM CUSTOMER')
```